# Securing communication between app and remote AWS services

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm using the `Android AWS SDK` in order to invoke my serverless entities. Each such entity is an `AWS Lambda` that does some processing and returns a response. The problem is that I didn't find a way to make the communication secured.

I tried to search how to make it under `SSL` with a custom `X509 certificate`, which I was adding to the client app(and check against in the handshake phase) but couldn't find out how to do this.

It's super important since I managed to configure my proxy client to listen to requests from the `AWS SDK` to my `AWS Lambda` service and see all of the data of the `requests` and `responses(parameters, keys, raw form data...)`, which is a huge red flag for me.

note: we do not use `AWS Gateway`.